# static int __init console_setup(char *str), what's _init for? can't find in C

Tags: linux

I am new to the linux, for function static int __init console_setup(char *str), it will return int, function name is console_setup, but what is _init meaning here? I tried to google, but no answer. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined and described in [`include/linux/init.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.1/include/linux/init.h).